# How to use conditional and biconditional symbols

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, logic

I have the following problem:

[image]

reduced row echolon form is:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 3 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & -2 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Is it correct to write an answer like this?

$x_3$ is free so we can set $x_3 = t$

$A\vec{x} = 0 \iff \vec{x} = t[-3, 2, 1]$

$A\vec{x} = \vec{b} \iff \vec{x} = [2, -1, 0] + t[-3, 2, 1]$

Im unsure about the usage of the biconditional.

Comment: What's $t$?. The calculation and the biconditional is correct.

Comment: Just a parameter

Comment: I asked, because it isn't nice written down. If you work with $\mathbb{R}$ I would prefer $Ax=0\Leftrightarrow x\in \{t(-3,2,1) | t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ or something like that...